# How to run npm and node on windows 11 correctly ? I am getting below error while trying to run npm install on windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

This is the error I am getting while I am trying to run npm install/ npm install nodejs-java on windows 11.
npm version - 9.6.1
node version -  v18.15.0
Visual studio - 2017

I tried several times but it's not working. How can I fix this issue ?
This is required to run a react based application. The same application works fine in mac.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nodejs-java
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
npm ERR!   java.cpp
npm ERR! c:\users\study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2535): warning C4996: 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor': Do signature check in accessor [C:\Users\Study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nodejs-java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\users\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\v8-template.h(838): note: see declaration of 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor'
npm ERR!   javaObject.cpp
npm ERR! c:\users\study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2535): warning C4996: 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor': Do signature check in accessor [C:\Users\Study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nodejs-java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\users\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\v8-template.h(838): note: see declaration of 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor'
npm ERR!   javaScope.cpp
npm ERR!   methodCallBaton.cpp
npm ERR! c:\users\study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2535): warning C4996: 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor': Do signature check in accessor [C:\Users\Study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nodejs-java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\users\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\v8-template.h(838): note: see declaration of 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor'
npm ERR!   nodeJavaBridge.cpp
npm ERR! C:\Users\Study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2535): warning C4996: 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor': Do signature check in accessor [C:\UsersStudy-clone-spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nodejs-java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\usersappdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\v8-template.h(838): note: see declaration of 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor'
npm ERR!   utils.cpp
npm ERR! c:\usersstudy-clone-spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2535): warning C4996: 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor': Do signature check in accessor [C:\UsersStudy-clone-spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nodejs-java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\usersappdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\v8-template.h(838): note: see declaration of 'v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor'
npm ERR! C:\Users\Study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nodejs-java\src\utils.cpp(487): error C2039: 'GetContents': is not a member of 'v8::ArrayBuffer' [C:\Users\Study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nodejs-java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
npm ERR!   c:\users\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\18.15.0\include\node\v8-wasm.h(18): note: see declaration of 'v8::ArrayBuffer'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.10 found at "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2017 (15.9.33423.255) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Study\\clone\\spring-reactjs\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Study\\clone\\spring-reactjs\\frontend\\node_modules\\nodejs-java\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Study\\clone\\spring-reactjs\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.15.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.15.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Study\\clone\\spring-reactjs\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.15.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Study\\clone\\spring-reactjs\\frontend\\node_modules\\nodejs-java',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Study\\clone\\spring-reactjs\\frontend\\node_modules\\nodejs-java\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Study\\clone\\spring-reactjs\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Study\clone\spring-reactjs\frontend\node_modules\nodejs-java
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-15T06_55_56_961Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this command in case of dependency problems

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

or did you need to create a react app the following command

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

to run the created app

```
cd my-app

npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it needs `node-gyp` and `python`. Run `npm i -g node-gyp` command to install node-gyp globally. And install [Python](https://www.python.org/) from official site.

**Edit:** Also, don't forget to add Python to path. There will be option while installing python, for adding the path to environment variables.